# Must Declare Scalar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have three separate table variables in my Function, 
1 of them is not giving me any errors, the other two are,
I haven't found anything Different Syntax-wise between them, but maybe I need more caffeine.

the error I am receiving is

> Must declare the scalar variable "@DispoTable".

```
DECLARE @CIDdisp INT

DECLARE @DispoTable TABLE 
(
    CaseID INT,
    Code INT,
    Description VARCHAR(150)
)
--Gather Data From filter
SELECT @CIDdisp = CaseID, @Code = Code, @Description = Description
FROM fnRecidFilter3(@CaseID,01,01)
-- Insert into Temp table
INSERT INTO @DispoTable (CaseID, Code, Description)
VALUES (@CIDdisp, @Code, @Description)
-- Merge the Temp Table with RecidReport Table
INSERT INTO RecidReport(Code, Description)
SELECT Code, Description 
FROM @DispoTable
WHERE (@DispoTable.CaseID) = CaseID
```

is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Can you post the working function too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't say:

```
WHERE (@DispoTable.CaseID) = CaseID
```

Instead you need to use an alias:

```
FROM @DispoTable AS d
WHERE d.CaseID = CaseID
```

But this clause makes no sense anyway. Did you mean to use a variable here? Perhaps:

```
FROM @DispoTable AS d
WHERE d.CaseID = @CIDdisp
```

?

Comment: I have a main Table that I am putting Data into. and I want the Data to be put into that table in a certain way so that I can take extraneous data out later. maybe I was over thinking the order of the where statement.

Comment: I don't understand what the `WHERE` clause is even supposed to be doing. But the reason you're getting the error message is because you can't refer to a table variable by name other than in `FROM` - elsewhere you need to use an alias. The comment about whether the `WHERE` clause makes sense is peripheral.

Comment: the reason why the First one wasn't throwing the Same Error was because I Cut and Pasted from a Stored Procedure and was using a temp table there, and forgot to change the '#' to a '@' in the where statement. otherwise the Alias fixed it, and I think it had something to do with the ( ) in the where statement as well

Comment: in the Main table I have some data in 3 columns I want to use this table to add columns where the CaseID matches so I don't have duplicate CaseID's

Comment: So maybe you meant `FROM @DispoTable AS d WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.RedicReport WHERE CaseID = d.CaseID);` - impossible to tell because your comment seems contradictory. I think that should be a separate question.

Comment: I have a lot of Stuff messed up in this function.  I am sort of learning how the sp's and Functions work as I go, and what I can and Can't do inside of each; I know the Basics of SQL pretty well, but never got into stored procedures and Functions.   I know what I want to do, now I just have to figure out where Sql Server will let me do it. thank you for your help